# Rabbit losing hair around face areas (eyes, nose and mouth)

Tags: health, rabbits

I recently purchased a rabbit from a pet store. During the purchase, the rabbit have already had a wound on his back. It seems going to be better. After 2 days, he shed the fur around his mouth and nose area, but I can't find the shedded hair in the cage area. The next day, he started to lose fur around his eyes. He stop drinking water and just eats carrots.

What may be the causes? Is it virus?

Comment: Can it be a stress symptom?
Is it in the wind? Try to cover it's cage for avoid any troubles like wind or sound too loud.

Comment: Your rabbit could have the sniffles, does your rabbit have a snotty nose or is sneezing?

Answer (score 1):

Could be allergies. I would consult a vet.